# Zend Framework 2 - Instantiating Class

Tags: class, zend-framework

Why do I have to provide the leading backslash when providing the path to a class? [\Zend\Validator\EmailAddress() and not just Zend\Validator\EmailAddress()]

> $validator = new \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress();
>
> $email = "example@example.com";
>
> if ($validator->isValid($email)) {
>      // email appears to be valid
>   } else {
>      // email is invalid; print the reasons
>      foreach ($validator->getMessages() as $messageId => $message) {
>          echo "Validation failure '$messageId': $message\n";
>      }
>   }

Thanks!

Comment: Have you declared a namespace at the top of whatever file you're in?

Comment: yes,use Zend\Validator\EmailAddress; But that needs the \ too. The namespace in my file is namespace Blog\Controller;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you've declared the namespace of `Blog\Controller` at the start of the class, with:

```
namespace Blog\Controller
```

This tells PHP that by default all classes referenced within that class are within the `Blog\Controller` namespace. So if you were to then do:

```
$validator = new Zend\Validator\EmailAddress();
```

what you are actually doing is:

```
$validator = new Blog\Controller\Zend\Validator\EmailAddress();
```

which would give you an error since that class doesn't exist.

If you prefix a class with the backslash, you're telling PHP that that class is not in your declared namespace, but instead is in the global space, which is why it then works.

You also said you've imported the `EmailAddress` class using `use Zend\Validator\EmailAddress`. This allows you to reference that class as simply 'EmailAddress'. So you change your code to:

```
$validator = new EmailAddress();
```

which is much more concise. This is one of the advantages of namespaces - it allows you to use *shorter* class names in your code.

Comment: Tim, Thank you so much. I am able to understand your notes very well and resolve the issue. Thanks!